# extract date from pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some issues while writting a function which return by month, year and the id of a doctor, the number of consultations he did.

The problem is: I have, as a date, any consultations of a doctor so I don't know how I can use this to sort by month of a year the number of consultations he did.

I have to write a function that returns the number of times a doctor visits a given month. The function will take as a parameter a doctor identifier, a
month and one year.

Here is the table consultation:

```
CREATE TABLE consultation(
    n_med       integer constraint fk_consultation_medecin references medecin(n_med),
    n_malade        integer constraint fk_consultation_malade references
                    malade(n_malade) on delete cascade deferrable initially deferred,
    date_consult    date,
    h_consult   integer not null,
    prescription    varchar2(128),
    examen      varchar2(128),
    constraint pk_consultation primary key(n_med, n_malade, date_consult)
);
```

and here is the function :

```
FUNCTION getNbConsult(id_med IN integer, mois IN integer, annee IN integer)  
    RETURN integer 
IS 
    nbConsult integer; 
BEGIN 
   select count(*) into nbConsult from consultation where N_MED = id_med and date_consult = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE ???)
   RETURN nbConsult; 
END; 
/
```

Comment: If you have a year and a month, create a date variable where the day portion is the first of that month.  Then it's a simple matter of `and date_consult >= that variable and date_consult < add_months(that variable, 1)`.

Comment: Something like this? select count(*) into nbConsult from consultation where N_MED = id_med and date_consult >= TO_DATE(mois||'/'||1||'/'||annee,'MM/DD/YYYY') and date_consult< (mois||'/'||31||'/'||annee,'MM/DD/YYYY');

Comment: You are on the right track.  You will have to cast your two integers to strings, put a leading zero on the month when required, and acknowledge that not all months have 31 days.

Comment: So here it is : select count(*) into nbConsult from consultation where N_MED = id_med and date_consult >= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(mois)||'/'||1||'/'||TO_CHAR(annee),'MM/DD/YYYY') and date_consult< TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(mois)||'/'||31||'/'||TO_CHAR(annee),'MM/DD/YYYY'); but I still don't know how to check the last day of a month

Comment: If you follow my initial suggestion exactly, it won't matter what the last day of the month is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_char(date_consult,'YYYYMM') = TO_CHAR( annee, 'FM0000' ) || TO_CHAR( mois, 'FM00' )` but then Oracle will not be able to use an index on the `date_consult` column (and would require a function-based index) instead you could use:

```
FUNCTION getNbConsult(id_med IN integer, mois IN integer, annee IN integer)  
  RETURN integer 
IS 
  nbConsult integer;
  month DATE := TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( annee, 'FM0000' ) || TO_CHAR( mois, 'FM00' ), 'yyyymm' );
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO   nbConsult 
  FROM   consultation 
  WHERE  date_consult >= month            
  AND    date_consult <  ADD_MONTHS( month, 1 );
  RETURN nbConsult; 
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how the year and month are specified in your situation but you could select records for a specific year and month as follows:

```
select count(*) 
into nbConsult 
from consultation 
where to_char(date_consult,'YYYYMM') = '201709';
```

Ah, integers. So you can change it to

```
select count(*) 
    into nbConsult 
    from consultation 
    where to_char(date_consult,'YYYYMM') = annee||lpad(mois,2,'0');
```

Comment: While this has the value of simplicity, it might execute slowly because it is filtering on a function result.

Comment: Well, why don't you write an answer?